# drupal measure author's publication efficiensy drupal 7

Tags: performance, drupal, publishing

I have made a drupal 7 site.

I'm looking for a solution for measuring the authors (blog writers, article writers) efficiensy.
I would like to see someweher, how many nodes are created by a user (author) per month and how many letters do these nodes contain.

Can you suggest me a modul or something else?

Thanks,
Tamás

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function authors_efficiency_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/authors_efficiency'] = array(
    'title' => 'Own Settings',
    'description' => 'Parent item',
    'position' => 'left',
    'weight' => -100,
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
  );
  // Need at least one child item before your section will appear.
  $items['admin/config/authors_efficiency/efficiency'] = array(
    'title' => 'Authors efficiency',
    'description' => 'Authors efficiency',
    'page callback' => 'authors_efficiency_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function authors_efficiency_page_callback($para=array()){
    $output= '';


    // define number of results per page
    $num_per_page = 50;

    $header = array('User','Month','Count','Length sum','Avarage length');

    // define sql to fetch results
    $query= db_select('node','n');
    $query->condition('n.status', '1');
    $query->condition('n.created', (time()-(120*24*60*60)), '>');
    $query->join('field_data_body', 'b', 'n.nid = b.entity_id');
    $query->join('users', 'u', 'n.uid = u.uid');
    $query->condition('b.entity_type', 'node');
    $query->addExpression('CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created)),\'-\',LPAD(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created)), 2, \'0\'))', 'node_month');
    $query->addExpression('SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(b.body_value))', 'node_char_length');
    $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)', 'node_count');
    $query->fields('n', array('uid'));
    $query->fields('u', array('name'));
    $query->groupBy('CONCAT(n.uid, \'@\', node_month)');
    $query->orderBy('node_month', 'DESC');
    $query->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');


    $count_query= db_select('node','n');
    $count_query->condition('n.status', '1');
    $count_query->condition('n.created', (time()-(120*24*60*60)), '>');
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(*)', 'node_count');
    $count_query->fields('n', array('uid'));
    $count_query->groupBy('CONCAT(n.uid, \'@\', CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created)),\'-\',LPAD(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created)), 2, \'0\')))');


    $count_query = $count_query->countQuery();
    $maxCount = $count_query->execute()->fetchField();;  

    $page = pager_default_initialize($maxCount, $num_per_page);
    $offset = $num_per_page * $page;

    $query->range($offset, $num_per_page);
    $result= $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    $rows = array();
    foreach($result as $record){
        $row = array(
                    $record->name,
                    $record->node_month,
                    $record->node_count,
                    $record->node_char_length,
                    round($record->node_char_length/$record->node_count),
               );
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Depending on the context there may be a better choice than this
    $output.=  theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
    $output.=  theme('pager');


    return($output);
}
?>
```